# Prove that $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ be the set of invertible $2\times2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$, the ring of integers modulo $2$. Is this a group under matrix multiplication?

The matrix $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}$ lives in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$, so the set is non-empty.

Since they are invertible matrices, then this would imply for all $x,y\in GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$, $(xy)^{-1}$ is in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$.

Is this a legitimate proof that $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ is a group?  Thank you for any help!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: No, that's not a legitimate proof.

Comment: There are only a few of those.. $2^4$ different ones. You can put them in an  operation table ( it will only be $16\times 16 = 256$ multiplications ) and see if they fulfill the group conditions. Is there an inverse element for all of them? Are they closed under multiplication? Are they associative?

Comment: @mathreadler There aren't $2^4$ elements.

Comment: If the elements are in the set $\{0,1\}$, aka 2 possibilities for each element, then there will be 2 raised to the number of elements such possible matrices. There are 4 elements in a $2\times 2$ matrix, therefore $2^4$ such matrices. No wait, such *invertible* matrices! Then $2^4$ will be an upper bound so there will be even fewer. You can still use the $256 \times 256$ table and then remove any row/column corresponding to an element not having an inverse.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, and the set $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a group for any field $\mathbb{F}$. I would go and prove the statement with the abstract field, for it usually makes figuring out what to do in the proof simpler.

Comment: @mathreadler: This group has six elements. Furthermore, the group is isomorphic to $S_3$. The simplest proof is to observe that $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_2)$ acts faithfully on the three non-zero vectors of $\Bbb{Z}_2^2$. It just happens that all three permutations of those three vectors preserve addition. It's actually not at all hard to see that because some of any two distinct non-zero vectors is the third vector.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How to show it has only six? I was thinking to try for all 16 and disqualify those whose part in the multiplication table don't fulfill the group axioms.

Comment: @mathreadler The quickest way may be to calculate the determinants. Also, the formula for the order of $GL_n(\Bbb{F}_q)$ has been explained many times on our site:
$$|GL_n(\Bbb{F}_q)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1}).$$ Here $q=n=2$, and the formula gives $(4-1)(4-2)=6$.

Comment: Basically: A) three alternatives for the top row (can't be all zeros). B) two alternative for the bottom row (can't be all zeros nor the same as the top row).